# How can I suppress certain messages from being echoed in the echo-area?

Tags: echo-area

Is there a way to filter out certain messages from being echoed in the echo-area while still being logged in to the *Messages* buffer ?

Use case scenario being an aggressive backward delete in the minibuffer yields a `Text is read-only` message when the point hits the prompt. I find this highly distracting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hack just about any function with `defadvice`, although debugging advised functions is quite difficult:

```
(defadvice message (around my-message-filter activate)
  (unless (string-match "Text is read-only" (or (ad-get-arg 0) ""))
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like advicing is the only way. I was hoping there was an inbuilt filter or something. BTW the above snippet does not log to the `*Messages*` buffer though that is easily fixed by changing the conditional to `if` and sending the string manually to the `*Messages*` buffer. I will wait for a day before accepting it.

Comment: AFAICT this doesn't work any messages in the echo area that get triggered by the C source. For example the end of buffer message.